# Pytrends: For-Loop leads to Error Code 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, server, google-trends

I tried using pytrends for extracting Google trends data. You can see the code I used below:

```
from pytrends import dailydata

words = ['aaa', 'bbb']

chunks = [words[i:i+1] for i in range(len(list_all))[::1]]
for chunk in chunks:
    res = dailydata.get_daily_data(chunk, start_year=2020, start_mon=1, stop_year=2020, stop_mon=12, geo = '')
    res.to_csv(chunk[0]+'.csv')
    time.sleep(60)
```

Without the for-loop everything works perfectly but as soon as I use the for loop (which I need to because I have a large number of requests), I get the following error:

**The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400.
Trying again in 60 seconds.**

Do you see where the problem comes from?

Comment: Google's api might have a request limit, so you can only send a certain number of requests to the API in a certain time.

Comment: They do have that, but that is error 429. I fixed that with the time.sleep(60) which should normally not lead to any errors. I've been using the interest_over_time() before and there it worked out this way.

Answer (score 1):

One chunk in chunks is a list of strings as you are building it as words[i:i+1] not words[i]. However, what I have seen from the get_daily_data API docs is that the first argument must be a string not a list of strings. This might lead to a bad request and explain the 400 code.

Comment: Great, that seems to work! Thank you so much!